# How sub-domains resolve to IP address?

Tags: networking

While doing nslookup for 2 subdomains, i am getting respective IP addresses. But when doing reverse DNS for those IP's they are not getting resolved to same domain. 
I am unable to understand the concept behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Regular (A/AAAA) and reverse (PTR) DNS records don't have to match. They're two different records.

If you lookup `www.google.com`, you'll get an IP address, but if you try a reverse lookup for that IP, you'll get something like `fra16s13-in-f228.1e100.net` and not `www.google.com`.

Comment: Hi Malt,Thanks for the response.

Comment: And how do i do reverse nslookup to resolve my IP to google.com. Because when doing network PT for an application, i was unable to get results as IP did not resolve to the particular domain name.

Comment: That might not be possible. There might not be any IP address whose PTR record is ‘www.google.com’. That’s just how it is. The terms “forward” and “reverse” dns are confusing, these dns records not really the opposite of each other.